# How to fix Apps Aren't Loaded Yet Error Django

Tags: django

hoping someone can help. I'm trying to run a script.py to populate my Django webapp and I am getting the following error:

Apps Aren't Loaded Yet

I've included pictures of the script [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uM66.png) and of my settings[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO4t0.png). Anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't import `User` before configuring Django

Comment: thank you so much! so simple....

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Django first before accessing some of its modules

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mynowandthen.settings')
django.setup()

# Do the usual Django stuff here
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

For more information:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage